# Can i avoid repetition in filebeat input settings?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, apache-kafka, elastic-stack, filebeat

I have an input settings like this (Proof Of Concept) and i will add more prospectors further on.

Can i avoid repetition of the multiline properties?

```
filebeat.prospectors:
  - type: log
    enabled: true
    paths:
      - /data/server/logs/inode-stage/inode-stage.log
    multiline.pattern: '^\['
    multiline.negate: true
    multiline.match: after
    fields:
      env: 'stage'
      app: 'inode'
  - type: log
    enabled: true
    paths:
      - /data/server/logs/inode-dev/inode-dev.log
    multiline.pattern: '^\['
    multiline.negate: true
    multiline.match: after
    fields:
      env: 'dev'
      app: 'inode'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible right now. Not sure how many variations you will have in your inputs, but based on your current example I would extract the `env` with [dissect](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/dissect.html). If you need something more powerful, you could even go for the [script processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/processor-script.html).